# Markerclusterer no Mapa com PHP echo XML

Tags: xml, google-maps, marker

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo um mapa olhando a api do google e o primeiro passo está concluído, trazer todos os estabelecimentos dentro do mapa, para conseguir fazer isso olhei a referência do google **Como usar MySQL e PHP com o Google Maps**. Agora sempre que abro o mapa me mostra vários markers dentro de São Paulo, mas para não aparecerem tão perto, quero utilizar o markerclusterer para juntar todos eles quando estiverem muito perto e aqui foi onde eu barrei, pois o código que escrevi para trazer os estabelecimentos no mapa é puxando via xml as informações do estabelecimento e o código de referência que estou usando para o marker é estático.

> Código sem MarkerClusterer

```
<script>
  var customLabel = {
    restaurante: {
      label: 'R'
    },
    bar: {
      label: 'B'
    }
  };

    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
//  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.5278805, -46.801652),
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.5505199, -46.6333094),
      zoom: 13
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl('http://app.liveclube.com/connectdata/', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });
    }

  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}
</script>
```

Depois disso, criei um outro mapa com a sintaxe do markerclusterer.

> Código do MarkerClusterer

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

  function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
    });

    // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
    var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    // Add some markers to the map.
    // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
    // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
    // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
    var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
      return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        label: labels[i % labels.length]
      });
    });

    // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
  }
  var locations = [
    {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
    {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
    {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124},
    {lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834},
    {lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968},
    {lat: -34.671264, lng: 150.863657},
    {lat: -35.304724, lng: 148.662905},
    {lat: -36.817685, lng: 175.699196},
    {lat: -36.828611, lng: 175.790222},
    {lat: -37.750000, lng: 145.116667},
    {lat: -37.759859, lng: 145.128708},
    {lat: -37.765015, lng: 145.133858},
    {lat: -37.770104, lng: 145.143299},
    {lat: -37.773700, lng: 145.145187},
    {lat: -37.774785, lng: 145.137978},
    {lat: -37.819616, lng: 144.968119},
    {lat: -38.330766, lng: 144.695692},
    {lat: -39.927193, lng: 175.053218},
    {lat: -41.330162, lng: 174.865694},
    {lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.439506},
    {lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.501315},
    {lat: -42.735258, lng: 147.438000},
    {lat: -43.999792, lng: 170.463352}
  ]
</script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
</script>
```

O problema deste código é que o locations é estático e eu queria pegar a informação que já tenho dentro do [connectdata.php](http://app.liveclube.com/connectdata)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém saberia me dizer como posso fazer para vincular ambos os códigos?

Answer (score 0):

A variável "**locations**" está no formato **JSON**, então você só precisa converter os dados do XML para o formato **JSON**.

Para facilitar você pode usar um arquivo javascript (.JS) JSON em vez de XML, e importar ele na sua página PHP/HTML

Exemplo de conteudo do arquivo (**marcadores.js**) :

```
locations = [
  {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
  {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
  {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124}
];
```

Exemplo de Import:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--import-->
    <script src="marcadores.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
      //criacao de mapa ========================
    </script>
...
```

Ou se quiser converter o teu XML para JSON, então tem esses exemplos aqui:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929478/xml-string-to-json-javascript